# If a superclass is very simple and only contains a single variable, is it worth moving to composition?

Tags: java, oop

Is there any benefit to having simple superclasses which act only as a storage place for a single variable:

```
public abstract class A {
    private Config value;

    public A(Config value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    protected Config getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(Config value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public C(Config value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

As opposed to no superclass and composition:

```
public class B {
    private Config value;

    public B(Config value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class C {
    private Config value;

    public C(Config value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

It wouldn't make sense for every single class containing an integer to extend a type specifically for holding the integer (as seen in the superclass example), so surely it is preferred to have no superclass and just use each `Config` individually?

I am having a hard time trying to find the boundaries of when to stop abstractions. Too many abstractions can become more of a sin than too little.

Comment: Simple question: Given whatever project you're working on, does having it make your code simpler or more complex? Related questions: Does it make it easier or harder to change features that are likely to change? Will you remember how it works in 6 months? Does the time you spend documenting it outweigh the time it saves you coding? Specific question for your example: What's the difference between a B and a C and do you ever care what that difference is (semantic differences *do* count, btw!)? List your pros and cons, the choice (which depends on the application) will become clear.

Comment: Do you have places where you need to use `B` or `C` **interchangeably**? Then it would make sense to have a *common interface*. Otherwise, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage in create classes with only one property. Think about it you are creating a lot of process only for one property when you are instantiating every class. At the the top level you have an abstract class as parent of the other clases, the abstract class are getting you the advantage of partially implement that class this mean that children classes can use some of those properties or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some easy guidelines specifically for your example:

1. Semantically, is a `B` an `A`? Is a `C` an `A`? If yes and yes then at least having the base `A` makes sense. If not then none of this makes sense for you. If the former is the case:
2. Do all `A`'s have a `Config`? That is, is a `Config` some intrinsic property of every `A` regardless of any subclass? If so then having the member in the base class makes sense. If not, then keeping the member in the subclasses (or e.g. having `A` -> `ConfigurableA` -> `B`/`C`/etc. if that makes more sense for you.)

Here's an exercise that might help with that second point: A `Bird` is a `Creature`. A `Cat` is a `Creature`. A `Parrot` and a `Robin` are `Bird`s. 1) How would you organize the class hierarchy here? 2) Where would you put a `wingspan` property? 3) Where would you put a `weight` property? 4) Where would you put a list of `wordsSpokenByParrot`?

Your goal is to make your work easier, now and in the future. If your code is making your work harder, then you shouldn't be doing it that way. It's pretty much that simple.

More generally: Given whatever project you're working on, does doing something make your code simpler or more complex? Does it make it easier or harder to change features that are likely to change? Will you remember how it works in 6 months? Does the time you spend documenting it outweigh the time it saves you coding? What's the difference between a B and a C and do you ever care what that difference is (semantic differences do count, btw!)? List your pros and cons, the choice (which depends on the application) will become clear.

> If a superclass is very simple and only contains a single variable, is it worth moving to composition?

I don't know, you tell us. Only you know what makes the most sense for the program you're currently writing, which might be different from the next program you write. It's not about sticking to some set of hard and fast rules, it's about you making life easy for yourself while getting the job done.